# Error en archivo xml : error: attribute ' ... ' not found

Tags: android, xml

Buen dia, tengo este archivo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#0202ff"
tools:context="matgic.com.matgic.Digits9">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_contenedor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtusername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            />



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coins"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtscore"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_coin" />

        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtscore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img0"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"


            android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtusername"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtusername" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/question"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/question"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img0" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"


            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img0"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img0"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"

            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignStart0="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img2"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img6"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img7"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img6"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img8"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img7"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/question"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/question"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img9"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img6"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/unknown"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/unknown"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/unknown"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/unknown"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unknown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img9"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="@string/digitsquestion1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnno"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/unknown"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="no"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnyes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnno"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnno"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/question"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/question"
            android:text="yes" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="logout"
            android:textSize="25sp" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

en Gradle Console muestra esto:

> error: attribute 'android:layout_alignStart0' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo indica el error:

> error: attribute 'android:layout_alignStart0' not found.

No encuentra el atributo `android:layout_alignStart0` en este `ImageView` :

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"

            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignStart0="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img2" />
```

**ese atributo en realidad NO es valido, debes cambiarlo a  `android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img1"`**, ejemplo:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"

            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img2" />
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, ese era el problema, saludos

Answer (score 1):

tienes un error de fin prematuro de los datos en la etiqueta RelativeLayout línea 2 revisa donde tienes un fin de tag que te falta
he validado tu xml en [xmlValidator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator)

Comment: Hola ger, en el caso de layouts .xml (Android), usar un validador para archivos .xml NO se debe usar y además no es útil ya que existen propiedades y atributos que no existen en un xml estándar.